# Why the announcements list sent e-mail (alert) doesn't have pictures?

Tags: list, email, alert, outlook

Created a SharePoint 2010 Announcements List, and I configured it to receive e-mail, and set it up so I could receive alerts every time anything changes in the list.
Sent an e-mail to the list and the items are added without a problem.

[image]

However, when I receive the email it doesn't include the image. It says: Right-Click here to download pictures. Doing so does not display any picture.  Any ideas what the problem may be? Is there a setting that control this?

Things I tried:

1. copy and paste image from internet into outlook (doesn't work)
2. copy local picture to body of e-mail (doesn't work)
3. Attach the picture is not sent in the e-mail.

[image]

Here is a snippet of the HTML in the e-mail body:

```
</style> </head> <body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"> <div class="WordSection1"> <p class="MsoNormal">I would like to sell this plane for $1M. </p> <p class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p> <p class="MsoNormal"><img width="875" height="500" id="irc_mi" src="/Lists/4Sale/Attachments/1/image001.jpg" alt="http://site.nitroplanes.com/ArtTech-AlphaJet-2.4Ghz.jpg"></p> </div> </body> </html>
```

If I understand it right the src="/list/..." is missing the

```
http://intranet
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the alert is including either a relative URL to the image or some internal URL such as servername/pathTo/Image where 'servername' is not generally accessible.  View the HTML source and find the image reference.  If it is anything other than the FQDN of the server, then you probably need to change the Alternate Access Mapping for your default zone to be the FQDN.

Comment: Added the HTML source in the description. It seems that the src doesn't include the http://intranet